# VBA nested for loop crashes

Tags: vba, excel

I have this function in VBA, everything works except when it reaches the `For` loop it just crashes and I have to close Excel and everything, not really sure how to fix it.

```
Private Sub checkDuplicates(x As Worksheet)
    Dim n As Integer, i As Long, j As Long

    Sort x
    addheader x, "checkDup."
    n = searchHeader(x, "checkDup.")
    x.Columns(n) = 1
    For i = 50 To 3 Step -1
        For j = 1 To 5
            If Not x.Cells(i, j) = x.Cells(i - 1, j).Value Then
                x.Cells(i, n) = 0
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `i = lastRow(x)` are you calling a function here?

Comment: yep another function in the same module, it returns an integer

Comment: Might want to post code for that?

Comment: sure it is simply lastRow = x.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

Comment: I have also tried it with just replacing lastrow(x) with a random number, still crashes

Comment: Can you edit the Question and provide the code for lastCol and lastRow functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "it crashes"? Does Excel simply quit stating it's not working any more? Or does your code just raise a run time error with an error message stating what the problem might be? In this case we would need to know the error message.

Comment: @ dave I got rid of the lastcol and last row and replaced it with integers, it still does not work, just to make it simpler

Comment: @leviathan Excel stops responding and I am forced to close it or wait for it to respond (which does not work. Once I press close program, excel briefly returns to normal then displays the error message "run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': method'_default' of object 'range' failed"

Comment: I am thinking it dies before the for loop... you're calling a lot of subs/functions. Comment them out one by one?

Comment: I have used the debug to step into the module until it reaches the specified sub, it performs fine until it reaches the first for loop upon which excel stops responding immediately.

Comment: What's your goal with "x.Columns(n) = 1"? I'm not testing it but if it worked did you want to have all that column cells value set to 1?

Comment: yes that is what it does

Comment: Could you check the Event Viewer to see if there are any application error associated with the crash of Excel?

Comment: You realize that's dropping a 1 into a million rows?

Comment: I can write better code for that later, the code still crashes if I comment out that line.

Comment: @Karlomanio I can't appear to find and event logs associated with the crash of excel

Comment: @Walter, there must be a log somewhere that gives an error when it crashes.  Did you look in eventvwr.msc and search the Office log or an application log referring to the error?  Also, maybe Microsoft will have a log somewhere for Excel.  Keep looking for an error.  The only thing I can think of is somehow you are exiting the worksheet when you are executing the code.  If you can't find a log, can you step through the loop and see what it is doing in your worksheet before it crashes?  That would help too!

Comment: @Walter - what is the simplest you can make the sub and it still crash? Have you tried re-typing the offending line (hidden character)?

Answer (score 4):

### Based on the comment-conversation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423636/vba-nested-for-loop-crashes#comment62352825_37423636), **your code isn't "crashing"**.

It's **working very hard** and accessing cell values in a tight loop, which is **the** single slowest thing VBA code can do, and you're doing it for a large number of cells.

Wait it out. Excel "isn't responding" because it's busy running your loop and keeping up with all the updates going on.

Here's something that *may* help it complete faster:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

' your code here

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

If that doesn't complete in a more reasonable amount of time, then you need to look into an array-based approach, where you dump the interesting range into an in-memory array, work against the array, modify the array values, and then dump the array onto the worksheet *in a single write*.

Comment: This would make sense but OP is using 50 for `i` and is still "crashing".

Comment: @findwindow Excel will always say "(not responding)" *whenever* there's VBA code running a loop and a user that starts clicking everywhere. Everything is running on a single thread.

Comment: OP may have really slow pc